# Says Loading question but opens an answer

Tags: discussion, android-app

See screenshot below for the issue.

I don't really have a good suggestion for this one. Th text could probably be changed to something generic like "Loading..." instead of "Loading question...".

[image]

Comment: Well, answers do belong to questions...

Comment: When I read Loading Question I take it to mean it's loading the whole question, which includes all answers, including the one you're linking to.